# Sidebar which can scroll but with the main content fixed

Tags: html, css, sidebar

I am attempting to create a sidebar which can scroll, but the main content on the right is fixed (no scroll).

But when I try to work around it does not work, so here is an example

**HTML**

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="outer-wrapper" class="is-open">
        <div id="inner-wrapper">
        </div>
        <div id="sidebar">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#sidebar {
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: -80%;
    width: 80%;
}

.is-open {
    //expose the sidebar by translating the wrapper
    -webkit-transform: translateX(80%);
    transform: translateX(80%);
}

#container {
    //disables horizontal scroll
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Here is the fiddle that might help with testing
https://jsfiddle.net/minheq/tn2no1o6/3/

Please, any advice on this?

Comment: Your question is confusing. You want the sidebar to scroll or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```css
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.container, .wrapper {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.content {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 0;
  background: #ddd;
  padding: 10px;
  padding-left: 230px;
}
.sidebar {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  padding: 10px;
  background: #849;
  overflow: auto;
}
.sidebar-content {
  width: 100%;
  height: 600px;
  background: #994;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="content">Lorem ipsum dolor</div>
    <div class="sidebar">
      <div class="sidebar-content">Amet dolor ipsum</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Make you sidebar `display:fixed` and `overflow-y: auto`.  The the main content DIV needs to have left margin larger than the width of your sidebar.

```
<div class="sidebar">
  ... sidebar stuff here ...
</div>

<div class="mainContent">
  ... main content stuff here ...
</div>
```

And your CSS:

```
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin:0;
}

div.sidebar {
  padding: 10px;
  display: block;
  width: 150px;
  position: fixed;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow-y: auto;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}

div.mainContent {
  margin-left: 180px;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

This will make the sidebar and the main content scroll independently of each other, and only when the content exceeds the height of its container.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kph8jxLv/

Answer (score 0):

```css
#content{
    width: 70%;
    margin: 0;
}

.one{
    height: 80px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color:red;
    margin: 0;
}

.two{
    height: 80px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color:green;
    margin: 0;
}

#sidebar{
    width: 30%;
    height: 250px;
    background-color: blue;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    position: fixed;
}

body, html{
    margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="content">
    <div class="one"></div> 
    <div class="two"></div>
    <div class="one"></div> 
    <div class="two"></div> 
    <div class="one"></div> 
    <div class="two"></div> 
    <div class="one"></div> 
    <div class="two"></div> 
</div>
<div id="sidebar">
    
</div>
```